# How to stop the looping statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a table number for each item in my database records, but i don't know how to stop the looping.

How can I stop it? Below is my codes. Help?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    for ($i = 1; $i < $row; $i++ ) { 
        echo'<tr>
                <td>'.$i.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['supplier'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['item_description'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['unit_cost'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
                <td>'.number_format($row['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
            </tr>';
           }
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that for loop:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$i++.'</td>
            <td>'.$row['supplier'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['item_description'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['quantity'].'</td>
            <td>'.$row['unit'].'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($row['unit_cost'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
            <td>'.number_format($row['total_amount'], 2, '.', ',').'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you did exacly like I did? $i++ ?

Comment: HAHA i put the $i=1; inside of while statement :D . sorry. BTW thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break;` word in your while.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 0):

Using the response of speccode, you can use break in a condition. 
For example :
`if (my condition) break;`

Comment: Well yea... You can use break to stop loop but "create a table number for each item"? 1,2,3 and so on? Or number of columns in $row? Then it should be count($row).